# AttributeError at /checkout/ 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'id'. can't access to my automactically created 'id model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm a beginner at django. It's my first time to post there. That's why feel free to point if I have done something wrong.

I'm doing 'e-commerce page' project. I'm using django 3.1.3. I can't get access to my 'id' model in my Order model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
# Create your models here.
from products.models import Product

User = get_user_model()

ORDER_STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('created', 'Created'),
    ('stale', 'Stale'),
    ('paid', 'Paid'),
    ('shipped', 'Shipped'),
    ('refunded', 'Refunded'),
)


class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ORDER_STATUS_CHOICES, default='created')
    sub_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    paid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    shipping_address = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    billing_adress = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

This is my view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.
from .models import Order
from products.models import Product

@login_required
def checkout_order(request):
    qs = Product.objects.filter(featured=True)
    if not qs.exists():
        return redirect('/')
    product = qs.first()
    user = request.user # without login_required there will be AnonUsers so we don't want it
    order_id = request.session.get('order_id')
    order_obj = None
    try: 
        order_obj = Order.objects.filter(id=order_id)
    except:
        order_id = None
    if order_id == None:
        order_obj = Order.objects.filter(product=product, user=user)
        request.session['order_id'] = order_obj.id
    print(order_obj.id)
    return render(request, 'forms.html', {})
```

I realized that in my try block I can't get access for 'id' model but don't know how to fix it since as far I know id model will be created automatically and there can't be 2 AutoField() fields. And I also tried to do with get() method `order_obj = Order.objects.filter(id=order_id)` but the result is the same.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I made a mistake when copy/pasting the code and confused people. So in the second if statement `order_obj = Order.objects.filter(product=product, user=user)` should be `order_obj = Order.objects.create(product=product, user=user)` with create method not filter(). Sorry for this mistake.

Comment: make sure that order object exist?

Comment: Yeah, I think there I did it:
qs = Product.objects.filter(featured=True)
    if not qs.exists():
        return redirect('/')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with this line

```
print(order_obj.id)
```

`order_obj` is not an instance of the `Order` model, it is an instance
of `QuerySet`. because `Order.objects.filter` returns a queryset not, a model instance.

to fix this add `.first()` to the end of your queryset filter statement.

```
order_obj = Order.objects.filter(id=order_id).first()
# and
order_obj = Order.objects.filter(product=product, user=user).first()
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response. The first line of your code was a solution. It turned out I did a mistake when copy/pasting the code. order_obj = Order.objects.filter(product=product, user=user) should be create() instead of filter(). Sorry for this silly mistake. I will edit my question so that I will not confuse others.